# Python: string not splitting correctly at "|||" substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in Pandas DataFrame that stores long strings, in which different chunks of information are separated by a "|||".
This is an example:

```
"intermediation|"mechanical turk"|precarious "public policy" ||| intermediation|"mechanical turk"|precarious high-level
```

I need to split this column into multiple columns, each column containing the string between the separators "|||".

However, while running the following code:

```
df['query_ids'].str.split('|||', n=5, expand = True)
```

What I get, however, are splits done for every single character, like this:

```
     0   1  2  3  4                                                  5
0        "  r  e  g  ulatory capture"|"political lobbying" policy-m...
```

I suspect it's because "|" is a Python operator, but I cannot think of a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `|`:

```
df['query_ids'].str.split('\|\|\|', n=5, expand=True)
```

or to pass `regex=False`:

```
df['query_ids'].str.split('|||', n=5, expand=True, regex=False)
```